# How to show number of students according to college name and display total number of students of each college

Tags: join, plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper, cursors

Table college:

> Block quote

```
create table college
(
    clg_code number(3) primary key,
    clg_name varchar(20)
);
```

Table stud_detail

> Block quote

```
create table stud_detail
(
    stud_no number(3) primary key,
    name varchar(10),
    dob date,
    clg_code references college
);
```

I have tried this trigger, now have to count total number of students in each college.

> Block quote

```
set serveroutput on;
```

declare
        cursor c_stud is select stud_no,name,clg_name from stud_detail s,college c where s.clg_code=c.clg_code;

```
    v_stud c_stud%rowtype;

begin
    for v_stud in c_stud
    loop
            dbms_output.put_line(v_stud.stud_no||' '||v_stud.name||' '||v_stud.clg_name);

    end loop;
end;
/
```

Values in college table

> Block quote

```
insert into college values (101,'Sahjanand');
insert into college values (102,'Gurukul');
insert into college values (103,'K.R.Doshi');
```

> Block quote

select * from college;

Values in stud_detail

> Block quote

```
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('abc','12-mar-1998',101); 
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('adsfbc','22-jan-1999',101);  
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('ac','13-feb-1995',101);  
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('ddbc','02-mar-1998',101);    
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('afdgc','09-sep-1996',101);   
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('adf','30-jun-1997',101); 
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('osif','24-mar-1996',101);    

insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('dfif','13-mar-1996',102);    
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('odffif','26-jan-1993',102);  
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('fsaf','30-mar-1994',102);    
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('vvhgf','08-jul-1995',102);   
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('odgf','19-sep-1997',102);    
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('dfgfif','12-oct-1998',102);  
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('dfgdif','24-feb-1996',102);  
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('sdgfif','21-aug-1998',102);  

insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('jc','22-mar-1994',103);  
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('charmi','26-dec-1998',103);
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('ritu','04-dec-1991',103);
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('ridddhi','26-may-1998',103);
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('khushbu','11-jul-1998',103);
insert into stud_detail (name,dob,clg_code)values('vaishali','23-feb-1999',103);
```

> Block quote

select * from stud_detail;

Trigger for primary key generation for stud_detail.

> Block quote

```
create or replace trigger tristud before insert on stud_detail for each row declare     pkey number(5); begin   select max(stud_no)+1 into pkey from stud_detail;   if (pkey is null) then      :new.stud_no:=1;    else        :new.stud_no:=pkey;     end if; end; /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, you just need a simple `COUNT`

SQL Query -

```
select clg_name, count(stud_no) count_of_studens
  from college c
  join stud_detail s
    on s.clg_code = c.clg_code
group by clg_name;
```

In a Anonymous block -

```
declare

cursor stud_record is 
select clg_name, count(stud_no) count_of_studens
  from college c
  join stud_detail s
    on s.clg_code = c.clg_code
group by clg_name;
BEGIN
   for records in stud_record
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line('College Name - ' || records.cld_name);
       dbms_output.put_line('Number of Students - ' || records.count_of_students);
   END FOR;

END;
/
```

p.s. you really should be using a sequence for primary key rather than a trigger.

Comment: Do i have to make another cursor nd put this select statement in that?

Comment: @JaicyJoseph - you don't need a cursor to run a select statement, you can run it as-is. Where do you want to show this data ?

Comment: declare
     cursor c_stud is select stud_no,name,clg_name from stud_detail s,college c where s.clg_code=c.clg_code;
     
     v_stud c_stud%rowtype;
    
    begin
     for v_stud in c_stud
     loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_stud.stud_no||' '||v_stud.name||' '||v_stud.clg_name);
   
     end loop;
 //Here i need to do that end;
    /

Comment: Its showing an error of not a single- group group function

Comment: @JaicyJoseph - Updated the answer. Added the `group by` clause and fixed the alias in the `JOIN` clause

Comment: Error Showing not a group by expression

Comment: @JaicyJoseph - the `group by` should be the columns which were are selecting on, can you check the answer again.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I got the answer